# Casting object to specified class best practice

Tags: c#, casting

I have a method that gets an `object` that can be of various types. Depending of the `type` of the `object` I need to do different actions. My current code is like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(object obj)
{
    int? someId = null;

    Class1 class1 = obj as Class1;
    Class2 class2 = obj as Class2;
    Class3 class3 = obj as Class3;
    Class4 class4 = obj as Class4;

    if (class1 != null && class1.SomeProperty != null)
    {
        someId = class1.SomeProperty.Id;
    }
    else if (class2 != null && class2.AnotherProperty != null)
    {
        someId = class2.AnotherProperty.AnotherId;
    }
    ...

    AnotherMethod(someId);
}
```

I am not quite satisfied with this code as I do have some unnecessary casts. Which would be the most efficient way to do such an operation? I was thinking about something like:

```
if (obj.GetType().Equals(typeOf(Class1))
{
    someId = ((Class1)obj).SomeProperty.Id;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why this method takes an object, does it have to ? what is the relation betweern Class1, 2 and 3.. ?

Comment: Yes it does have to. And the various classes are not related.

Comment: If you are worried about performance. Don't. It is needless microoptimization. You should be more concerned about clarity of code and extensibility. You should make it as easy as possible to add new class to this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case (get single value of a variable), it could be more efficient to use switch-like approach, something like:

```
public int? GetSomeId(object obj) {
    Class1 class1 = obj as Class1;
    if (class1 != null)
    {
        return class1.SomeProperty != null ? class1.SomeProperty.Id : (int?)null;
    }

    Class2 class2 = obj as Class2;
    if (class2 != null)
    {
        return class2.AnotherProperty != null ? class2.AnotherProperty.AnotherId : (int?)null;
    }

    ....

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I do like this solution most as it exactly does what I want (no multiple and unnecessary casts) without bending my code (which is a little bit more complicated than in my post).

Comment: @SimonLinder The problem of multiple unnecessary casts is still there: every time you pass `Class4`, you get three unnecessary casts; two casts for `Class3`, and so on. If all classes in the call of `SomeMethod` are represented evenly, this approach removes exactly half of unnecessary casts, rather than eliminating them all. The problem is inherent in the structure of your approach, with a chain of `if`s, which is linear by its nature.

Comment: I've put some code that avoids unnecessary casts if you look my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Both alternatives are pretty bad, because they do explicit casts, and dispatch by checking the type manually. This is error-prone, and leads to inevitable maintenance headaches when you expand the list of types that your method needs to handle.

Starting with .NET 4.0, you have a better option - dispatch using `dynamic`:

```
public void SomeMethod(dynamic obj) {
    SomeMethodImpl(obj);
}
private void SomeMethodImpl(Class1 obj) {
    // Perform actions specific to Class 1
}
private void SomeMethodImpl(Class2 obj) {
    // Perform actions specific to Class 2
}
private void SomeMethodImpl(Class3 obj) {
    // Perform actions specific to Class 3
}
private void SomeMethodImpl(Class4 obj) {
    // Perform actions specific to Class 4
}
private void SomeMethodImpl(object obj) {
    // Catch all
}
```

Now you can place the code specific to a class in its own overload of `SomeMethodImpl`, without running a chain of conditional statements. Expanding your method to handle additional types is simple as well - all you need to do is adding another overload.

**Note:** I assume that the signature of `SomeMethod` must remain the same - in other words, you cannot address this problem simply by *overloading* `SomeMethod`.

Comment: Why do we need `SomeMethod(dynamic obj)`... the code works fine with other methods alone I guess :)

Comment: @ramb00 Not exactly. What if in OP's case there is a technical need to have a *single* method that takes objects of any kind - for example, because the method is part of an interface implementation?

Comment: Good point... Won't `SomeMethodImpl(object obj)` take care of this? Why do we still need dynamic??

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first try doing this without casting. You can define an interface and explicitly implement this interface for each `Classn`. I assume `Classn` classes are not third party and you can modify them.

```
public interface IIdProvider {
    int? Id { get; }
}

public class Class1 : IIdProvider {
    int? IIdProvider.Id { 
        get {
            return SomeProperty != null ? SomeProperty.Id : null;
        }
    }
}

public class Class2 : IIdProvider {
   int? IIdProvider.Id { 
        get {
            return AnotherProperty != null ? AnotherProperty.AnotherId : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Having this, `SomeMethod` does not care where the Id comes from. If you want to add `Class5`, `Class6` etc you do not have to modify `SomeMethod`. Instead each newly added class will take care of the `Id` thing itself. Having this, we can do the following.

```
public void SomeMethod(IIdProvider obj)
{
    AnotherMethod(obj.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Polymorphism??**

```
public void SomeMethod(Class1 class1)
{
    AnotherMethod(class1.SomeProperty.Id);
}

public void SomeMethod(Class2 class2)
{
    AnotherMethod(class2.NewProperty.Id);
}
.
.
.
```

Instead why not call `AnotherMethod(class1.SomeProperty.Id);`,.. `AnotherMethod(class2.NewProperty.Id)` directly if that is all you wanted to do...

If you really want to check if the object is of certain type use `if(obj is Class1)` instead of casting it

Comment: this is not Polymorphism. it's called _method overloading_

Comment: This does not provide a drop-in replacement for OP's method. In particular, when you replace his class with yours, client code must be recompiled to take advantage of the overload.

Answer (score 0):

`as` keyword exists for programmer conciseness. It gets translated to

```
Class1 class1 = obj is Class1 ? (Class1)obj : null;
```

I thinks go with `as` as it looks more readable and also does not affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
if (obj is Class1 && ((Class1)obj).SomeProperty)
    someId = ((Class1)obj).SomeProperty.Id;
```

Final code would look like this:

```
if (obj is Class1 && ((Class1)obj).SomeProperty)
    someId = ((Class1)obj).SomeProperty.Id;
else if (obj is Class2 && ((Class2)obj).AnotherProperty)
    someId = ((Class2)obj).AnotherProperty.Id;
else if (obj is Class3 && ((Class3)obj).OnceAgainAnotherProperty)
    ...
```

---

*In every `if` and `else if` conditions, if the first check `obj is X` fails it will not do the second `((X)obj).XProperty`. So at the end of the day, only two casts will be performed, even if your object as the type `Class4`.*

Comment: What if `SomeProperty` is `null`?

Comment: @SimonLinder Then you have to check `SomeProperty`. I edited my answer.